# Solve for $x$, $\ x^2+(4x^3-3x )^2=1$, given that $x=\cos\alpha$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I know that it would be:

$\cos^2\alpha+3\cos^2\alpha=1$ by identities

then it would be:

$4\cos^2\alpha=1$

dividing $4$ to both sides:

$\cos^2\alpha=\frac{1}{4}$

square both sides:

$\cos\alpha=\pm\frac{1}{2}$

After this, what should I do?

Comment: All six roots are real and in $[-1,1]$ and so are the cosine of some angle.

Comment: No idea why you get  $\cos\alpha^2 + 3\cos\alpha^2=1$ (and it looks wrong). You can use $\cos(3\alpha) = 4\cos^3\alpha - 3\cos\alpha$ to attack the problem.

Comment: Hint: try to reduce it to $\cos(2\alpha)+\cos(6\alpha)=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by op, using $\ (a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$ to solve for the values of x, given the equation $\ cos^2\alpha+\cos^23\alpha=1$ is:

$\pm\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}, \pm0.9238..., \pm0.3826...$

Answer (score 1):

Plugging $x = \cos \alpha$ we get
$$\cos^2\alpha + \cos^2 3\alpha = 1$$

(since $\cos 3\alpha = 4\cos^3\alpha - 3\cos \alpha$) which implies
$$\sin^2\alpha = \cos^23\alpha \iff (\sin\alpha - \cos3\alpha)(\sin\alpha + \cos3\alpha) = 0$$

---

**Case 1.** Let $$\sin\alpha - \cos3\alpha = 0$$
or $$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \alpha\right) - \cos3\alpha = 0$$ or $$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4} + \alpha\right)\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4} - 2\alpha\right) = 0.$$
This gives either
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4} + \alpha\right) = 0$$
or
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4} - 2\alpha\right) = 0$$
Solce them individually.

---

**Case 2.** Let $$\sin\alpha + \cos3\alpha = 0$$
This case is similar to the Case 1.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but I did another method. To avoid the long computations, I ended up with $\ cos^2\alpha+\cos^23\alpha=1$ and using $\ (a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$ to solve for the values of x.